# One-way function constructed by multivariable polynomials

Tags: one-way-function, hard-core-predicate, polynomial, np

Although the conjecture regarding the existence of one-way functions remained open, there are numerous NP-based methods for constructing diverse one-way functions, including DL, lattice, and subset sum problems.

Recently, I have been endeavoring to employ multivariable polynomials in the construction of a one-way function, as follows:

$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)=\sum^{N}_{i=1}a_i \cdot x_i$, where $x_i\in \{0,1 \}$ and $a_i \in Z_p$, $p$ is a large prime.

The total number of potential outcomes for such a polynomial is given by the expression $\sum_{k=2}^N\binom Nk$. For the case where $N=1024$, the total number of combinations is very large.

However, I have no idea how to prove or demonstrate that such a function is a one-way function for small inputs.

Another concern arises if the constructed one-way function can be reduced to the subset-sum problem, as suggested in comments. However, this [lecture note](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Esalil/cs127/fall13/lec7.pdf) asserts that "The subset-sum problem is NP-complete but that does not necessarily imply that the function is one-way." I am perplexed by this point.

Comment: Isn't that just (search) subset sum?

Comment: what's your exact definition of "small input"?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by  "NP-based methods" for constructing OWF. I am not aware of a single construction of a OWF based on an NP-hard problem. The issue is that OWF asks for average-case hardness, whereas NP-hardness is worst-case complexity.

Comment: @Maeher Can the construction be directly reduced into subset sum problem? Could you give me some hints or related references? thank you!

Comment: @kodlu "small input" means the input of the multivariable polynomial is small. For instance, in the case of $N=1024$, the length of input is also $N$.